# CSS3 animating multiple properties of SVG object not working in Safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari

I'm trying to animate an SVG element in Safari 6 & 7 with CSS and keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 150px);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}
```

But only the opacity is working, and if I remove the opacity, the translate works. How can I animate both properties at the same time? In Chrome it works fine.

Here's a [jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/zedit/1/edit)

You can see side by side that it is working on the div element, but not on the element inside the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of course was that I had to use "fill-opacity" instead of "opacity", which is not supported on SVG elements... Duh!

Here's the fixed [jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/fuvolo/1/edit?css,output).